# remove cachebuster in AngularJs API call

Tags: angularjs, api, browser-cache

I am using ngCacheBuster in my app.js and

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('User', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('api/users/:email', {}, {
                'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
                'search':{
                    url:'api/search',
                    method:'GET',
                    params: {
                        email: '@email'
                    },
                    isArray:true
                }                  
            });
        });
```

and calling as

```
User.search({email:$scope.nameQuery},function(result,headers){
         $scope.users = result;
     });
```

when I am trying to call this method, it is showing as 
http://localhost:3000/myApp/api/search?cacheBuster=1488208210950&email=searchString

is there a way to remove cacheBuster from my url
I want something like 
http://localhost:3000/myApp/api/search?email=searchString

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you changing objects that search returns?

Comment: yes, searchString I am passing from controller